# Unable to add google sign in in ios 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, google-signin

I had followed all the steps given in developers.google.com.

When I try to do

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
```

Got clientID from my plist file.

But it shows linker errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: No I am not using pods. Manually configured.

Comment: Try linking SafariServices.framework to your app?

Comment: Now I am getting different type of error

`googlesample[6109:168567] -[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc229726250
2015-10-16 18:59:38.934 googlesample[6109:168567] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc229726250' `

Answer (score 3):

I had above mentioned issue.

Just needs to add "**SafariServices.framework**" to your project which is available in iOS 9.

[image]

Comment: Now I am getting different type of error `googlesample[6109:168567] -[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc229726250 2015-10-16 18:59:38.934 googlesample[6109:168567] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc229726250'`

Answer (score 1):

As per Google documents: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/, you should do the following:

1. Include SafariServices.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework to your Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.
2. Add "-ObjC" (without quotes) to your Target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 0):

So far I tried I am unable to complete this with google sign in.

So I have used Google-Plus sign in mechanism to get the user details.

Please refer to this

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

And also now I can share the content and people list/

Comment: Don't use this framework, Since google had many new changes to the new framework. If you use this your app will be rejected by Apple, because of some redirection issue.

Comment: @Prakash any solution